# How to update a row based on min/max values in related rows

Tags: sql, performance

I tried to make the title as generic as possible, but I do have a very specific example of this in mind:

I have a table Table in which my rows have a StartDate and an EndDate. Each row will also be associated with an ID. For the sake of simplicity, let's assume to start that every EndDate is currently NULL.

I want to populate the EndDates with the following logic:

The EndDate for row X should correspond to the minimum of the StartDates of all other rows having the same ID as row X and having StartDates greater than the StartDate of row X.

So far the only solution I've come up with involves looping row by row and doing update statements row by row, which has terrible performance. I'm a little lost on this one. I loop over something like the following, using a temporary table that holds the rows I'm interested in (the ones with null end dates):

```
UPDATE BaseTable 
SET EffectiveEndDate=Minimum.Date 
from (
select min(BaseTable.StartDate) as date, TempTable as RowId 

FROM TempTable INNER JOIN BaseTable 
on BaseTable.ID=TempTable.ID 

where TempTable.row=@row 
and BaseTable.StartDate > TempTable.StartDate 
group by TempTable) Minimum 
where BaseTable.Id=Minimum.RowId
```

Comment: What is the solution you came up with?

Comment: Slightly too long, it's a loop plus a statement like this:UPDATE BaseTable
SET EffectiveEndDate=Minimum.Date
from
(select min(BaseTable.StartDate) as date, TempTable as RowId
FROM TempTable
INNER JOIN BaseTable
on BaseTable.ID=TempTable.ID
where TempTable.row=@row
and BaseTable.StartDate > TempTable.StartDate
group by TempTable) Minimum
where BaseTable.Id=Minimum.RowId;

Comment: Sorry for formatting but I don't know how to format these comments well. I should point out the TempTable holds information about the rows I want to change in this case (the ones with null end dates)

Comment: Post a code to elucidate your text.

Comment: I'm actually thinking I can drop the looping and use that same basic structure with an update... but I'll have to test it now to see if that actually works or not.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you would specify your RDBMS, but with SQL Server 2012 you can use the analytical functions `LEAD` and `LAG`. Based on your description I think the following would work:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    startdate,  
    LAG(startdate) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY startdate DESC)
FROM Table
ORDER BY id, startdate DESC;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2455f/1)

**EDIT:**

The same should be possible with older versions of SQL Server, but you have to write some code to simulate the `LAG` function as it is new in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Yeah, my fault. I should've specified SQL Server. I'll have to take a look at this and see how the performance compares to the other option. Thanks.

Comment: Ah. This won't actually work for my purposes because I don't want to update the EndDate if the next StartDate isn't strictly greater than it. Someone else might find this useful though.

Comment: I think my query does what you describe, but I could be wrong. The rows are ordered by startdate in descending order. LAG will pick the previous row, based on the order by this will be the minimum startdate of all startdates higher than the current startdate. If there is no previous row (there is no higher startdate) then the value will stay NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to do this:

```
update t
    set EndDate = (select min(t2.StartDate)
                   from t t2
                   where t2.id = t.id and 
                         t2.StartDate > t.StartDate
                  )
    where EndDate is null;
```

This is standard SQL so it should run in most databases.  In MySQL, you might need an additional level of subqueries.

Comment: Yeah, I just ended up coming up with something like this myself and it works great. I guess I should've fiddled with things for a bit longer before I posted the question, but I felt a little out of my depth at the time.